# Convert 'Date' String to specific format

Tags: ruby, regex, string

i have a column transformation string:

```
ctr = 'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

this string can be in any format like 'dd/mm/yyyy' OR 'yy/dd/mm' OR 'YYYY/mm/dd' OR anything in the date format.

I need to read this value and convert this to something like:

```
**input => output**
mm/dd/yyyy => %m/%d/%y
dd/mm/yyyy => %d/%m/%y
yy/mm/dd => %y/%m/%d
```

and so on, so that this value can be used as a parameter to the function as follows:

```
time = Time.parse("17-Nov-2011").strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

Comment: “I want to read this value and convert this to something like”—so read and convert, what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'mm/dd/yyyy'.gsub(/(?<l>\w)\g<l>+/, "%\\k<l>".downcase)
#⇒ "%m/%d/%y"
```